# Custom button for cocos2d

Tags: button, cocos2d-iphone, nsinvocation

I was working on creating my custom "Button" class... Im not using CCMenuItems because I need some flexibility in my buttons.

My implementation is the following:

```
DMenuButton : CCSprite <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
```

When created, the button receives a `target` and `selector`, and builds an `NSInvocation`. When touched, the invocation is called. I will use this buttons mainly to go from one layer to another.

**The problem** is that when going from a layer to the next, and then back to the previous, something strange occurs: either no sprites are loaded into the next view or an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is thrown.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

PS: My theory is that it has to do with the NSInvocation and the "dealloc" method.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It already exists solution for custom buttons for cocos2d if you want: https://github.com/YannickL/CCControlExtension